# How to stream a blob video in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have a video named `video.mp4` I want to stream it in a video tag in HTML, I tried too many answers from other questions and none of them worked.

```
var URL = this.window.URL || this.window.webkitURL;
var file = new Blob(["./video.mp4"], {"type": "video\/mp4"});
var value = URL.createObjectURL(file);

console.log(value);
video.src = value;
```

When I tried the code above it printed a blob, but when I want to play the video it doesn't work and shows this error in the console:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.`

Comment: You are not running the same code as in the duplicate, BTW. You are missing the `video.load()` step at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`new Blob` cannot be used to directly read a file. You may need something like instantiating a `XMLHttpRequest`. Also look at `<video>` element documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video. You need to specify `<source>` elements with `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var vid= document.createElement("video");
var vidsrc= document.createElement("source");
vidsrc.setAttribute('src','video.mp4');
vidsrc.setAttribute('type','video/mp4');
vid.appendChild(vidsrc);
document.body.appendChild(vid);
```

This code simply creates a new video element with a source element and adds it to the document body.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make the src as a blob

Comment: @Navspace The question seems to imply that he wants it as a <video> - "I want to stream it in a video tag in HTML"